# JavaScript redirecting 3rd-party Library access to window object

Tags: javascript, global-variables

We're using a 3rd party library (which we can't hack) which posts results to the Window object as properties (global object, as such). To get around this, so far, we've encapsulated the code in an iframe so that we can use the data without polluting the rest of the web site:

```
frame.window.annoying_variable
```

This is okay, but less than optimal (just plain ugly to my sensibilities). Is there a way of "redirecting" the access to these variables from the window object to another object?